# Count the number of operations within a for loop using a function. When the condition is met, subtract 1 from the base number of the variable: Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to write this code correctly, provided that ChakCak_After = 2 is outside the class
The task of the code is that whenever the condition is met in the for loop, a number will be missing from ChakCak_After. If I do not check, the number will be preferred as it is
And of course, if the condition is met, I want to change the ChakCak_After value outside the class with the new value that came out of the class
Anyone have a solution?

```html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver




Driver = webdriver.Chrome( service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

ChakCak_After = 2
class In_Cookies:
    def __init__(self):
        Driver.get("https://outlook.live.com/")
        ChakCak_URL = Driver.current_url
        ChakCak_URL_split = ChakCak_URL.strip().split("/")[3]
        Gam3 = "https://outlook.live.com/" + ChakCak_URL_split
        url_chask = "https://outlook.live.com/owa"
        if Gam3 == url_chask:
            ChakCak_After -= 1

            print("Conditions are met")

        elif Gam3 != url_chask:
            print("لم يتم استيفاء الشروط")
            pass



In_Cookies()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any for loop. So its possible I m answering wrong question, i will try asnswer question asked in headline. Maybe someone else would have more elegant and refined solution.

1)The quite crude way, I would adress something outside of function (altrough there are no real logical way, to not put it it into function input then output...) is something like this:

```
Count1=0
Variable=99 #dont know

def Function(Something):
  global Count1
  global Variable
  Count1+=1
  If Count1>xxx:
    Count1=0
    Variable-=1
  #rest of the function
```

I hope this helped at least a bid. And I think some seniors there would have less barbaric answer.

P.S: Be always carefull in "namespace poulution" when using global.

Comment: You can see the full code here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A23YGJeUdDFEkhgQOI2bUJzm53uKN0Je/view?usp=sharing